# How to hide action bar from splash screen?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, splash-screen

I am trying to hide the action bar from Splash Screen but it's not working. 
Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.foodcode">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"   >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Xml for Splash Screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".SplashScreen"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="FoodCode"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    />
```

Splash screen Java File

```
package com.example.android.foodcode;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

Handler handler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    handler=new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent=new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    },2000);

}
}
```

Comment: `        `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);` - inside `onCreate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have specified `android:windowActionBar` as false for your theme. May be try to declare your theme like this in your style.xml

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```